How many times does the function $r = 2 + \sin(\theta)$ pass through $x = 1$ in Cartesian coordinates?
How many times does the function $r = 2 + \sin(\theta)$ pass through $x = 1$ in Cartesian coordinates? What is the best approach? I tried to do a conversion into Cartesian and then substitute but didn't get anywhere.

Try putting both equation into polar coordinates or Cartesian. And try to add what you have attempted so far.

If you only need the number of times it intersects, and not the positions on which this happens, I think of your problem less algebraically and more from an analysis point of view as follows. This becomes possible because the angular frequency of the radius of your curve is  low enough (i.e., $r=2+\sin(\omega\theta)$ with $\omega=1$).
You can easily verify that the radius of the curve is (strictly) increasing in the first orthant, i.e., for $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$, and (strictly) decreasing in the $2^{\text{nd}}$ orthant $\theta\in\left[\frac\pi4,\frac\pi2\right]$.
On the $3^{\text{rd}}$ and $4^{\text{th}}$ orthants the radius remains positive, so the curve does not interfere with our reasoning on the first two orthants.
Moreover, at the positive vertical (Cartesian) axis $y$ your curve attains a value of $r=2+\sin\left(\frac\pi4\right)=2$ which lies above the point that the horizontal line $x=1$ intersects the same axis.
Hence, this curve must intersect the horizontal line exactly two times. The same is true for any horizontal line $x=\alpha$ with $\alpha\in[0,2)$, exactly once for $\alpha=2$, and nowhere for $\alpha>2$.

Do the substitution $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and $$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ and put $x=1$ and recall that $$\sin(\arctan(z))=\frac{z}{z^2+1}$$ and get the equation $$2\sqrt{y^2+1}+y=y^2+1$$ Simplify it further to get $$y^4-2y^3-y^2-2y-3=0$$
Let $y^4-2y^3-y^2-2y-3=f(y)$ 
Now $f(0)=-3$ and $f(3)=9$ so there is at least one real root. But since all the coefficients of $f(y)$ are real so it can't have just one real root. So this means that $f(y)$ has at least two real roots. We can also see that $f(-1)=1$
It is easy to see that $f'(y)>0$ when $y>3$ and $f'(y)<0$ when $y<-1$
So $f(y)$ will have only two real roots.
Hence there are two points of intersection.
